# eclipse-pydev disappeared after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04. I had eclipse installed with the pydev environment. After the upgrade eclipse seemed to hang during first start. So after some time I killed the process. Second start went well but the pydev menu entires disappeared (new pydev project, preferences-pydev, etc). I removed pydev in eclipse, then re-installed eclipse from software-center and finally installed pydev again via eclipse "install new software". Eclipse shows pydev as installed but it is still not visible/usable.

Can anybody give me advice? My installed versions are:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (amd64), 
Eclipse 3.8.1, 
PyDev for Eclipse   5.0.0.201605051159

Comment: After some research work I found out, that the pydev plugin has some unsatdisfied dependencies:
'com.python.pydev
     org.python.pydev
         org.eclipse.e4.ess.swt.theme

Comment: (Again, I was too slow:)
Further information:  In my installation the pydev plugin has some unsatdisfied dependencies:
'com.python.pydev -->  org.python.pydev -->        org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme, org.eclipse.e4.ui.services'
The dependency from, .e4. modules seems suspicious to me, because ubuntu 16.04 brings the pretty old eclipse version 3.8.1.
I installed the new "Mars" version from the eclipse download page in my home folder where the pydev plugin seems to work, but this version is unstable on my system (several hang-ups). 
So I have no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Pydev 4.5.5 works!**

Finally I tried to install older versions of pydev via the links provided on 
http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/index.html

Here I used version 4.5.5, the highest version that doesn't require java 8.
This works together with the eclipse 3.8.1.

Although I have installed openjdk 1.8 pydev doesn't seem to find a java 8 API.
The possible reason is that the highest java version the osgi framework provides ist 1.7 !
The relvant configuration entry is (might be):

```
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6,JavaSE-1.7
```

Maybe this is the solution until Canonical provides an Eclipse with an updated osgi framework.
To avoid the installation of  inconpatible pydev 5.0 or higher during eclipse's software update function one should not use the standard pydev update site (http://pydev.org/updates).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PyDev 5 does not work in Eclipse 3.8 anymore. See other user's report in [pydev-perspective-not-showing-after-install-on-eclipse-3-8 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879334/pydev-perspective-not-showing-after-install-on-eclipse-3-8).

In the [installation page](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) of PyDev, the latest PyDev version to be used is listed below:

- Eclipse 4.5, Java 8: PyDev 5.2.0
- Eclipse 3.8, Java 7: PyDev 4.5.5
- Eclipse 3.x, Java 6: PyDev 2.8.2
- Python 2.5 or older: PyDev 5.5.0

My PyDev can work in Eclipse 3.8 by manually installing PyDev 4.5.5. It can be downloaded in [PyDev for Eclipse - SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/).

After downloading the zip file, extract the contents of the zip file in the following folder and restart Eclipse.

```
     ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261
```

If you do not have the folder, see the section **Installing with the zip file** in the [installation page](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) for hints.

I do not have Java 7 installed. My PyDev 4.5.5 can appear in Window->Preferences->PyDev in Eclipse 3.8 with Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

If I use the latest sources, eclipse will say "sources are not found". So I have to use https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/4.5.5/ as the software source. It will work. My system is Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bits.

Comment: please a little explanation would be help based on your own experience with this same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: will this better?